# Set-Variable : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'server.js'

Tags: node.js, express

I was trying set NODE_ENV development enviroment and it's not working, here the response in the terminal

```
At line:1 char:1
+ SET NODE_ENV=development nodemon server.js
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Va  
riable], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,  
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetVariableCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

try each one seperately:

```
SET NODE_ENV=development
nodemon server.js
```

Answer (score 0):

If your OS is windows then you need to explicitly install the package 'win-node-env'. check below command to install

```
npm install -g win-node-env
```

Note: -g is to install globally and its is optional.

After successfully 'win-node-env' installed type below command to set the env

```
set NODE_ENV=development
```

or

```
set NODE_ENV='development'
```